# How do I get rid of extra space in between items in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap's grid to layout a form within a modal. There is too much space in between the label and the input element, and if I have two form controls in one row there is too much space between them. I am using 3 columns for each element, any less for any of them and I get word wrapping or clipping.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Start Time:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3 margin-top-sm">
                <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="timepicker" data-bind="value:startTime" id="StartTime" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                </div>
        </div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3">End Time:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3 margin-top-sm">
                <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="timepicker" data-bind="value:endTime" id="EndTime" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: So you want them to be aligned left as close as possible?

Comment: do they have to be inline?

Comment: I want to reduce the space between the label and the control, and I want to reduce the space in the middle, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I've altered your HTML and CSS to get this desired result. Instead of using `cols-*` I used `spans`, and `row-fluid`

HTML:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="span6">
                  <label class="control-label">Start Time:</label>
                  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="timepicker" data-bind="value:endTime" id="EndTime" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                  </div>   
               </div>
               <div class="span6">
                  <label class="control-label">End Time:</label>
                  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="timepicker" data-bind="value:endTime" id="EndTime" />
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                  </div>
               </div>            
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.span6{
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 40%;
   margin-left: 6%;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/NGOvQy)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the solution is to use a vertical form (labels above controls), then why does it require custom CSS?

Comment: Since models are only so big I thought it would be more friendlier to put them above leaving you extra room for the input fields.

Comment: It just worked out easier that was in order to get your input fields inline. IF you want to get the labels inline as well it's going to take a bunch of reformatting from your current markup.